# The thinking behind "4 times 5 is 12, and 4 times 6 is 13, and 4 times 7 is-oh dear! I shall never get to 20 at that rate!" from Alice in Wonderland?

Tags: number-theory, puzzle

Excerpt from Lewis Carroll's *Alice in Wonderland*:

> "Let me see: four times five is twelve, and four times six is thirteen, and four times seven is-oh dear! I shall never get to twenty at that rate!"

My questions:

> What mathematical machinery might the writer have had in mind when writing down the sentences above? Could one reengineer Carroll's thoughts behind? Is there any explanatory hint/link/allusion in Carroll's work or somewhere else?

I know that Carroll was a mathematician. So, there must be something out there...

Comment: It's not correct, and there is no modulus in which it is correct. "Adding four is adding one" is only true mod 3 and trivially mod 1.

Comment: Are you sure ?i mean you have to apply wonderland mathematics.

Comment: Well, if we interpret times as plus and work in base $7$.  But that is probably not intended.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Do you mean "Is there an interpretation of mathematics in which Alice's statement makes sense and is true?"  Because obviously four times five is not twelve.

Comment: I took this problem from a puzzle book,so i guess it asks for some interpretations.Btw i am emailing Lewis Carrol to ask him what he meant.

Comment: "I am emailing Lewis Carrol to ask him what he meant."  Okay, now you're just trolling.

Comment: that part was just to have some laugh,but the problem was serious.no need to downvote dude...

Comment: @Jhon: your e-mail won't get to Prof. Dodgson if you persist in misspelling his *nom de plume* $\ddot{\smile}$

Comment: hahha yeah i see that,you're right.thanks for editing.

Comment: There's glory for you!

Comment: This question should be re-opened. It's a mathematical puzzle serious enough to considered by [Martin Gardner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Gardner) in his [Annotated Alice](http://www.amazon.com/The-Annotated-Alice-Definitive-Edition/dp/0393048470). The solution accepted solution below was presented in [this NYTimes review of that book](http://wordplay.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/10/14/gardner-4/?_r=0).

Comment: I also think it should be reopened. As André Nicolas mentioned we can be using base 7 and addition. Then we will reach 20, but not if we do modulo 14.  We can get modulo by summing on a circle, then we can represent this summing with complex numbers and then we actually get multiplication too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This blog has a suggestion](http://io9.com/5907235/a-math-free-guide-to-the-math-of-alice-in-wonderland)

The idea is that she is doing calculations in base 10 but the answers are coming out in different bases ...

$4 \times 5 = 12 $ ( in base 18 )

$4 \times 6 = 13 $ ( in base 21 )

$4 \times 7 = 14 $ ( in base 24 )

So she is expressing $4n$ in base $3+3n$

indeed she can't get to 20 that way - if she could, $n$ would be a solution to $4n=6+6n$ which has solution $n=-3$

Comment: The following (very short) paper in Historia Mathematica discusses the matter: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0315086076900355. In particular, it attributes this interpretation to Alexander L. Taylor and even suggests a certain interpretation of the White Queen's instruction: "Now, here you see, it takes all the running you can do to keep in the same place. If you want to get somewhere else, you must run at least twice as fast as that."

Answer (score 2):

We have $4\cdot 5=20,\ldots ,4\cdot 10=40$. Assuming that one "has to stop" there (because one does stop there in elementary school), it would correspond to $12,13,14,15,16$ and $17$ in the "wrong" counting. So we will never reach $20$. Of course, there are many other possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

In theory there are other possibilities...

Imagine that

$$x\circ y=5x-8^{6-y}7^{y-5}$$

and it reads as $x$ times $y$.

So,

$$4\circ y=20-8^{6-y}7^{y-5}.$$

In concreto
$$4\circ 5=20-8\cdot7^{0}=12 \text{ and } 4\circ 6=20-8^{0}7^{1}=13$$

(and $4\circ 7=20-8^{-1}7^{2}=20-\frac{49}8...)$

---

PS: It can be shown easily that $x\circ y$ $(y=5,6,7,...)$ will never reach $4x$.

Comment: I would like to know a question that all philosophers agree is well posed, philosophically.

Comment: Here is one: "Is there a question that all philosophers agree is well posed, philosophically?"

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier one.

Take this.

$4\times n=4+n+(4-1)=n+7$

This way, $$4 \times 5=5+7=12$$ $$4 \times 6=6+7=13$$ $$4 \times 7=7+7=14$$

Now, note that a multiplication table usually continued up to $12$ only.
[Ref.](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,,-2264,00.html)

In that case, we would have

$$4 \times 5=5+7=12$$ $$4 \times 6=6+7=13$$ $$4 \times 7=7+7=14$$ $$4 \times 8=8+7=15$$ $$4 \times 9=9+7=16$$ $$4 \times 10=10+7=17$$ $$4 \times 11=11+7=18$$ $$4 \times 12=12+7=19$$

And it would not reach $20$.